# JSON - setting path for Python in visual studio code

Tags: python, json, visual-studio, path, settings

I am working with a YouTube instruction video and there person on the video has search the json settings files with "python.p" and python.python.path line comes up that he uses to set the default to a version of Python, but in my version of "json settings" I do not fine this choice.  What would I search for in the latest version of json settings to be able to select this path for python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Steps are:

1. Click on settings icon present at bottom left of vscode screen
   [image]
2. In the top right of screen, you should see `Open Settings (JSON)` option
   [image]
3. In the next screen, within double quotes start typing `python.p`, you should start seeing all the suggestions & options available
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

its a problem of vscode version, newer releases indicate python.pythonPath is being deprecated in favor of python.defaultInterpreterPath.
So if you try to set your variable "python.defaultInterpreterPath" to point to your desired interpreter, this will solve your problem.